# Getting RGB values from an int image (Java)

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm attempting to work out the area of a greyscale image, I'm aware that I could use getRGB() if it was a buffered image, but i'm using a toolkit so it is therefore a int image.  I just want to ask how I can get the pixel value? I've included my code below

```
import iptoolkit.*;

public class FindArea {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String imageDir = "C:/Users/John/Dropbox/finalYear/Project/Leaves/";
    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
    int area = 0;

    IntImage src = new IntImage(imageDir + "bg7.jpg", 256, 256);
    src.displayImage(); //displays the image in a window

    for (int row = 0; row <= src.getRows(); row++)
    {
        for (int col=0; col <= src.getCols(); col++)
        {
            //if(src.pixels[row][col] >= 0)
                area++;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("The area of the leaf is:" +area);     
}
```

Comment: The javadoc of your *toolkit* is your friend. If there is none, drop it immediately, like a hot, foul potato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int  pixel = src.pixels[row][col];
int  red = (pixel & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
int  green = (pixel & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
int  blue = pixel & 0x000000ff;
// and the Java Color is ...
Color color = new Color(red,green,blue);
```

based on [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0257.html) for BufferedImage, but principle is same.

Comment: Thanks for the help! its just the top line is causing problems (int pixel = src.pixels[row][col]; any idea what would be causing that?

Comment: @John What exactly is the problem ? Did you make sure that `row, col` are in valid range ?

Comment: I get an error message that look like this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 256.  Does this mean that pixel needs to be an array?

Comment: @John No, that probably means that you provide `row` or `col` value that is out of range of pixels [two-dimensional] array, which I suppose is your image size : `Width x Height`

Comment: @John Try to change your loop conditions to : `row < src.getRows();` i.e. replace `<=` with `<`. Same for `col`

Comment: Thats it! Your a legend thanks for persevering with me, it been a big help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe to remember that bits in an RGB value are ordered like that:
8 bit of R | 8 bits of G | 8 bits of B
But it also depends on the type of image that you are using.
Use some bit operators like shift << and >> and mask the value with a and operator &.